# How can I set up correctly malabar- mode in emacs?

Tags: maven, emacs

I been trying to install malabar mode in emacs, and I saw that I should have installed maven. Well, the problem is that I currently installed malabar-mode and already put the load path.

```
;;Malabar mode
(require 'cedet)
;(semantic-load-enable-minimum-features) ;; or enable more if you wish ---(I don't know the function of this line but doesn't let me start emacs correctly)
(require 'malabar-mode)
(setq malabar-groovy-lib-dir "~/.emacs.d/elpa/malabar-mode-20140303.946")
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.java\\'" . malabar-mode))
```

I don't know what is the load path of "malabar-groovy-lib-dir".
The malabar commands are available when emacs starts but when I call for example:

> malabar-compile-file

In the minibuffer says:

> searching for program: does not exist the file or directory, mvn

I've already installed maven and exported the load path for execute in terminal.

So I don't know how to set up correctly malabar-mode.
Also there is not much information about it.

somebody can help me?

Comment: If you can actually call `malabar-compile-file` then presumably that library is very much present and correct. From the error, the only problem seems to be with `mvn` (or possibly whether the path for `mvn` is in Emacs' `exec-path`?). You should confirm for us that you can execute `mvn` from a shell, and where it lives, and whether it lives in a directory covered by `C-h v exec-path`?

Comment: `M-x customize-group RET malabar` might be useful (I'm guessing; I've never used it).

Comment: @phils I din't know about the exec-path!
I searched about it in customize and I added the path of maven directory(the same that I put in the PATH of the shell). After that, I tried again the 
malabar-compile-file 
and the message in the minibuffer wasn't the same but appears another message:
"opening input file: does not exist the file or directory, ~/.malabar_mode/classpath"

I guess now, there is a problem with my lack knowledge about maven..